# How to avoid Parquet MemoryManager exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, parquet

I'm generating some parquet (v1.6.0) output from a PIG (v0.15.0) script. My script takes several input sources and joins them with some nesting. The script runs without error but then during the `STORE` operation I get:

```
2016-04-19 17:24:36,299 [PigTezLauncher-0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob - DAG Status: status=FAILED, progress=TotalTasks: 249 Succeeded: 220 Running: 0 Failed: 1 Killed: 28 FailedTaskAttempts: 43, diagnostics=Vertex failed, vertexName=scope-1446, vertexId=vertex_1460657535752_15030_1_18, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1460657535752_15030_1_18_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:parquet.hadoop.MemoryManager$1: New Memory allocation 134217728 exceeds minimum allocation size 1048576 with largest schema having 132 columns
    at parquet.hadoop.MemoryManager.updateAllocation(MemoryManager.java:125)
    at parquet.hadoop.MemoryManager.addWriter(MemoryManager.java:82)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.<init>(ParquetRecordWriter.java:104)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:309)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(PigOutputFormat.java:81)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.output.MROutput.initialize(MROutput.java:398)
    ...
```

The above exception was thrown when I executed the script using `-x tez` but I get the same exception when using mapreduce. I have tried to increase parallelization using `SET default_parallel` as well as adding an (unneccessary w.r.t. my real objectives) `ORDER BY` operation just prior to my `STORE` operations to ensure PIG has an opportunity to ship data off to different reducers and minimize the memory required on any given reducer. Finally, I've tried pushing up the available memory using `SET mapred.child.java.opts`. None of this has helped however.

Is there something I'm just missing? Are there known strategies for avoiding the issue of one reducer carrying too much of the load and causing things to fail during write? I've experienced similar issues writing to avro output that appear to be caused by insufficient memory to execute the compression step.

EDIT: per [this source file](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/MemoryManager.java#L125) the issue seems to boil down to the fact that `memAllocation/nCols<minMemAllocation`. However the memory allocation seems unaffected by the `mapred.child.java.opts` setting I tried out.

Comment: I appear to be hitting a max memory allocation limit. Not sure yet if this is a configuration on the cluster I'm using or if this is a simple configuration I need to set but am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this finally using the parameter `parquet.block.size`. The default value (see [source](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.java#L59)) is big enough to write a 128-column wide file, but no bigger. The solution in pig was to use `SET parquet.block.size x;` where `x >= y * 1024^2` and `y` is the number of columns in your output.